# Работа с цветами C#

Tags: c#, color, цвета, изображения

У меня есть пиксель с каким-то цветом. Я точно знаю, что на его основной цвет был наложен белый #FFFFFF и при наложении получился (к примеру) №808080. 
Есть ли возможность вычислить основной цвет, который был до наложения белого?
Как можно вычесть цвет из цвета? Пробовал вычитать aRGB цвет - не получается.

Прошу объяснить или доказать, что такого не может быть.

Comment: А что означает "наложен"?

Comment: @VladD , к примеру у меня есть форма белого цвета. С opacity 0.1 . Я делаю скриншот и получается чуть не естественные цвета, так как присутствует белый цвет с формы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте считать. Пусть фон раскладывается на компоненты `r`, `g`, `b`, а ваш наложенный цвет -- `r1`, `g1`, `b1`, opacity = `alpha`. Тогда результирующий цвет имеет компоненты `R = r * (1 - alpha) + r1 * alpha`, `G = g * (1 - alpha) + g1 * alpha`, `B = b * (1 - alpha) + b1 * alpha`.

Если у вас есть значения `r`, `g`, `b` и `alpha`, можно легко подсчитать:

```
r1 = (R - r * (1 - alpha)) / alpha
g1 = (G - g * (1 - alpha)) / alpha
b1 = (B - b * (1 - alpha)) / alpha
```

Подсчёт возможен, конечно, если `alpha != 0`, то есть от нового цвета хоть что-то осталось :)

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: исходный фон r, g, b; накладывается цвет r1, g1, b1; результирующий цвет R, G, B. Если у вас дано r1, g1, b1 и R, G, B, можно вычислить r, g, b аналогично:

    r = (R - r1 * alpha) / (1 - alpha)

и т. д.

Comment: @VladD , вы значения цветов используете в 0..255? Просто если в этом промежутке, то после решения, у меня получается почти такой же цвет(R G B), который получился при наложении.
r1g1b1 у меня всегда белый с прозрачностью 0.1. может в этом загвоздка?)

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: да, 0..255. А чему у вас равны r1g1b1, RGB и alpha? Например, если вы накладываете цвет `#FFFFFF` с opacity = 0.1 и получаете `#808080`:

    R = 0x80
    r1 = 0xff
    alpha = 0.1
    r = (R - r1 * alpha) / (1 - alpha) = (0x80 - 0xff * 0.1) / 0.9
      = (128 - 25.5) / 0.9 = 113.88 ~= 114

Comment: В общем, цвет "пленки" #FFFFFF с opacity 0.1 . Видимо я с 808080 явно ошибся, простите. 
Полученный цвет у меня #191919.
Вообще, искомый цвет должен быть #000000 в данном случае (но он может быть и другим. Его и надо искать)
@VladD, Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: Ну так всё ж правильно:

    r = (0x19 - 0xff * 0.1) / 0.9 = (25 - 25.5) / 0.9

Понятно, что 0х19 -- округлённое значение, так что `-0.5/0.9` и даёт наш 0.

Comment: @VladD , да, верно.
Вот только сейчас столкнулся с проблемой перевода цветов. 
В какой тип цвета преобразовывать пиксель от GetPixel , чтобы посчитать, а потом, чтобы я смог перевести его в RGB обычный.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: а какой тип возвращает GetPixel?

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: у `System.Drawing.Color` есть же поля `R`, `G`, `B` :)

Comment: @vladD, оуу. Так как мне правильно записать формулу?) и обратно перевести в #RRGGBB формат?) У меня мозг отключился)

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов: ну, (1) получаете значение по формуле, типа `double`, (2) округляете до целого, (3) если меньше нуля, будет ноль, (4) если больше 255, будет 255. Чтобы сконструировать снова Color, возьмите [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Что то типа того, наверное:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
 static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);

//получаем цвет 
IntPtr hdc;
int x,y;
Color clr = Color.FromArgb((Int32)GetPixel(hdc, x, y));
```

Плюс может еще пригодится два линка:

> http://habrahabr.ru/post/60085/
>
> http://www.realcoding.net/articles/glava-6-metody.html

Comment: я чуть не понял как с этим работать. Библиотеку я подключил, но как вызвать правильно? @markgenuine

Comment: o_O
А это с вопросом хоть как-нибудь связано?